# Efficient way for the following code

Tags: python-2.7, performance

I saw this problem on hackerrank.com, the problem is to find a 4 letter palindrome from a given string which can be a long string also.
Constraint is as follows:

[image]

where, |s| is the length of the string and a,b,c,d are the positions of the corresponding letters in the palindrome.
I found out the solution for this, but it isn't efficient enough, as in during the processing time it gives 'time out' error. The code is as follows:

```
s='kkkkkkz'
n=0
c_i,c_j,c_k,c_l=0,0,0,0
for i in range(len(s)): 
    j=0;c_i+=1
    while j>=0 and j<len(s):    
        c_j+=1
        if j>i: 
            k=0
            while k>=0 and k<len(s):    
                c_k+=1
                if k>j: 
                    l=0
                    while l>=0 and l<len(s):    
                        c_l+=1
                        if l>k: 
                            a=s[i]+s[j]+s[k]+s[l]
                            if a[0]==a[3] and a[1]==a[2]: n+=1
                        l+=1
                k+=1
        j+=1
print n
```

I thought of noticing the number of times each loop runs, which right now is 7,49,147 and 245.

It is still better than the techniques I followed before, but I am not able to to do better than this.

Suggestions please ?

Comment: "find a 4 letter palindrome from a given string" is ambiguous. Give us a more precise problem description.

Comment: I've made an edit ! @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the following, but this will still not be efficient enough. Scores 12/40 ..

```
import itertools

s=WHATEVERSTRING
n=0
for a in itertools.combinations(s, 4):
    n += (a[0] == a[3])*(a[1]==a[2])
print(n)
```

A working solution is to go down the following route: create a set of unique characters in the string, and map substring pairs to a dictionary. Then count all the occurrences of pairwise pairs.

```
from collections import defaultdict as di

data = [x for x in s.strip()]
chars = set(data)

sum_a = 0
for c in chars:
    a = 0
    b = di(int)
    double_pairs = 0
    for d in data:
        if d == c:
            sum_a += double_pairs
            double_pairs += b[c]
            b[c]+=a
            a += 1

        else:
            double_pairs += b[d]
            b[d] += a
print(sum_a%(10**9+7))
```

Comment: What is that score ? How can one calculate that 'efficiency' score ?

Comment: It means that it still times out at 28 of the data sets. Transferring the same code to PyPy will speed it up somewhat, but the data sets in this challenge are big to the point of having python encounter performance issues.